# Is there any way to read .env files in macOS?

Tags: macos, environment-variables

I created the .env file using the command and created variables like `token_id="13423edq234"` and so on. I don't want to use an external package like dotenv to read the file. I just want to know if there's any way to load the .env file that I've created so that it can be read by Python. Also I don't want to add the env variable to zprofile.

```
vim .env
```

and in the Python 3 shell,

```
import os
os.environ['token_id']
```

and it says, it's not defined.

Comment: What do you mean to tell us by `vim .env`?

Comment: Also this is not really a Python problem. If the environment variable exists, it can be accessed by Python, or any other program.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Agreed. I didn't want to get the .profile populated with custom env variables. I've found a way for Unix operating systems and I've added my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Main criteria for searching for a solution is to not populate the .profile or .bash etc files with custom environment variables. I've found a solution that works quite well for me.

[direnv](https://direnv.net/#use-cases) is a package that I came across. It works with Unix based OS. Since I use a mac with zsh shell, it works amazing. Here's the link to [install direnv](https://direnv.net/docs/installation.html).

After you follow the installation instructions, create a .envrc file and write your custom env variables, in my case, it would be like this in the .envrc file.

```
export token_id="13423edq234"
```

The best part is that it loads and unloads the variables automatically so your .profile stays clean. Let me know if you have any doubts.

Answer (score 11):

You can source it before running it:

```
$ source .env
$ python
>>> import os
>>> os.environ['token_id']
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me. It still throws the key error.

Comment: I forgot to say you should use the `export` keyword, which means you should change the content of your `.env` to `export token_id="1234"`.

Comment: This was exactly what was needed to temporarily set a list of env variables from a file.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Vaibhav, I use [direnv](https://direnv.net) with the following `.envrc` file:

```
[ -f secrets ] && eval $(cat secrets | sed 's/^/export /') || echo "no secrets file"
```

Then you can have a `secrets` file (or call it `.env` if you like and update the `.envrc` file accordingly):

```
MY_ENV_VAR1 = foo
MY_ENV_VAR2 = bar
```

The `sed` part of the `.envrc` allows you to optionally include the `export` statement in the `secrets`/`.env` file.